# iTunes hangs at "Step 6 of 7. Importing photos"

Tags: itunes, mobile-iphoto

Everytime I connect my iPhone (4 or 5) to iTunes (v. 12.0.1.26), it begins syncing but hangs on step 6 of 7, "Importing photos".

[image]

Comment: iTunes doesn't import photos, it only exports them. iPhoto imports them.... unless i missed a meeting;-)

Comment: I meant importing photos from iPhoto

Comment: then could you clarify your question? Use the edit button just underneath.

Answer (score 6):

1. Quit iTunes
2. Delete `~/Pictures/iPod Photo Cache` (may or may not exist)
3. Go to `~/Pictures/iPhoto Library
4. CTRL+click > Show Package Contents
5. Delete `iPod Photo Cache` inside the library
6. Try syncing again.

Worked for me.

Comment: For anyone else finding this post, the above answer worked for me, even though I had to skip step 2 since I didn't have a cache at that location (OSX 10.10).